# Building firefox error: c compiler cannot create executables

Tags: firefox, compiler-construction, build, makefile, configure

I'm trying to build firefox but I'm having some problems. I currently have Visual Studio 2008 Team Suite (trial if that matters).

My mozconfig file:

```
# Firefox
ac_add_options --enable-application=browser
mk_add_options MOZ_OBJDIR=/c/mozilla-build/mozilla-central/objdir-ff-release
mk_add_options MOZ_MAKE_FLAGS="-j4"

# Java XCOM
ac_add_options --enable-javaxpcom
ac_addoptions --with-java-include-path=/f/Applications/x64/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/include
ac_options --with-java-bin-path=/f/Applications/x64/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/bin

# XUL RUNNER
mk_add_options MOZ_CO_PROJECT=xulrunner
ac_add_options --enable-application=xulrunner
```

Note: Visual studio is installed to C:\Program Files (x86)

My environment variables:
http://paste2.org/p/401924

Any ideas?

The actual error says that the compiler "cl" can't create executables

Comment: Could we see the actual error and the command line produced to cause it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by using the 32-bit build environment instead of the 64-bit

Comment: Mozilla is dropping support for building on x86. Don't do this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

The file you linked to appears to be targeted towards a Linux/MinGW32/Cygwin build environemtn (note how the directories are specified and separated in the `PATH` variable, as well as others). Try fixing that and see if it helps, if not try reading http://groups.google.com/group/mozilla.dev.builds/browse_thread/thread/038fba57b3dbc1c6.